# Is PhoneGap Application is Single Page Application model like Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova, single-page-application

I want to develop multiple page applications.Is it needed  to load all the scripts and css file in each html file?

or We need to manage it in single index file itself ?
Do we need to write all pages in single index.html file using separate div with data-role="page"    or we can create multiple html file for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes phonegap has single page model, single page is good option over multiple page application with phonegap.But you can create it on both ways if you are going with multiple page application and having multiple html pages then also it's not required to load all the css and js stuff in every html pages you can declare it once and then you can use that js and css in all other pages as well.

**Multi-Page Apps**

Multi-page applications function more like traditional web pages.  Each “page” or HTML file contains a finite and discrete set of functionality, and has limited client-side dynamic updates.  A page is loaded, content is displayed, the user interacts with it, and then another page is loaded.  These pages can be loaded from the local file system or from remote servers. This style of architecture works for many developers, however there are three notable drawbacks to this approach.

First, there is the transition between pages. Not only are there visual display artifacts when pages are loaded and unloaded, but you also lose anything in-memory in JavaScript.  This includes framework libraries, collected data, and so on.

**Single Page Apps**

This approach enables you to create web apps that feel more like apps instead of web pages. Once the PhoneGap js library has been initialized, you never have to re-initialize it. By leveraging the single-page architecture, you will not lose data that is resident in memory, and you can manage the transition of content from one visual state to another.  Many MVC/development frameworks leverage this approach for building applications.  However, if you are leveraging the web view’s history management, then you have to manually manage URL fragments and history behaviors.